# Prevent Isolated storage deletion Silverlight 4 OOB

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, isolatedstorage

I have developed one OOB SL4 applicaton for a food chain, and it stores outlet bills locally in isolated storage, and these bills gets uploaded when Internet connection would be available. All is working fine.

But I have seen that if I open silverlight configuration dialogue->isolated storage, can delete the isolated storage of the application. So If there are 1000 bills are pending to upload gets deleted.

Is there any way to prevent the same?, I don;t think so , I know My documents is one more place, but I am looking for  alternate way to store data safely?

I tried the Comtoolkit but seems that behaviour is not consistent and not production quality code

Comment: Checking http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/resources/documentation/grouppolicysettings.aspx it seems there is no configuration to prevent this. I think this is a matter of user education.

Comment: Getting the Isolated storage thru code is very restricted and it is quite secure in terms of physical location, but for user perspective it is very easy to delete and disabled by end user.There should be something to prevent the user to delete/disable the IS.

Comment: @anees: What prevents the user from uninstalling the whole app?

Comment: AnthonyWJones:you can not prevent user from uninstalling the app, one gotcha is there, don't show the install menu by marking the event as handled in Mouserightclick event handler.But you need to do Layout root of all pages. and for installing give a button for the same.            But when you unistall OOB application, the Isolated storage remains there

Answer (score 1):

As @NestorArturo states it [seems](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/resources/documentation/grouppolicysettings.aspx) there is no configuration to prevent this.

However, an alternative, for an [out of browser application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is to use the file system.

> File system access. Trusted applications can access System.IO types
>   and related types that are otherwise unavailable to Silverlight. These
>   APIs provide direct read and write access to files in user folders on
>   the local computer. For more information, see How to: Access the Local
>   File System in Trusted Applications.

A third alternative is to write your own COM component; via this technique, you can gain full access to the system.